# Close secoundary database in wordpress

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress

I have two website. first one is in wordpress and second one is in corephp.
My Question is that i am connection database by $wpdb.

```
/* Core php database */
$newwpdb = new wpdb( 'username', 'password', 'database', 'localhost' );
```

Database connection is done. Now i am fetching some data using second database. After fetching i want to close the connection of core php database.

I have checked but not found any solution of it.
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/117495/database-connection-close

So anybody knows than please help me for solution.

Thanking in advance

Comment: You **did** find a solution, but it didn't work for you. Please explain why, because it looks very much like the question you linked to does address your issue.

Comment: In above url if i am using this @mysql_close( $mydb->dbh ); than wordpress connection is also closed so it is not usefull to me. and unset($mydb); menas it not closing the connection but it only blank the value of variable.